# marker icon on plotly scattermapbox not updating

Tags: plotly, mapbox

I am using plotly's scattermapbox to render a map and trying to change the symbol. I have been using `circle` for point coordinates and need to update to a `marker` symbol instead. When i update the symbox in the code, the map defaults to circle.

```
data.append({

                        "type": "scattermapbox",
                        "lat": df['Lat'],
                        "lon": df['Long'],
                        "name": "Location",
                        #"hovertext": rent,
                        "showlegend": False,
                        "hoverinfo": "text",
                        "mode": "markers",
                        "customdata": df.loc[:,cd_cols].values,
                        "marker": {
                            "symbol": "marker",  | defaults to circle
                           # "size": 18,
                            "opacity": 0.8,
                            #"color": "black"
                            }
                    }
        )
```

`marker` is a valid symbox based on the documentation here:

https://plotly.com/python/reference/scattermapbox/#scattermapbox-marker-symbol
https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/

Answer (score 1):

- reference this answer [How to create a symbol/button on a Plotly choropleth map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70072898/how-to-create-a-symbol-button-on-a-plotly-choropleth-map/70087231#70087231) for some of the explanation.  Simply *maki* icons do not work as markers in **plotly mapbox**
- have taken approach of sourcing SVG for marker from *maki* or *font-awesome* then convert it to **geojson**
- for purpose of this have sourced UK hospitals and used a black marker
- IMHO it's worth still using circle markers if you want hover info.  You won't get any from layout / layers

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import requests, io
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import shapely.geometry
import svgpath2mpl
import numpy as np

# create shapely multi-polygon from maki or font-awesome SVG path
def marker(name="star", source="fa"):
    def to_shapely(mpl, simplify=0):
        p = shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(
            [shapely.geometry.Polygon(a).simplify(simplify) for a in mpl]
        )
        p = shapely.affinity.affine_transform(
            p,
            [1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0],
        )
        scale = 1 if source == "maki" else 10 ** -2
        p = shapely.affinity.affine_transform(
            p,
            [1, 0, 0, 1, -p.centroid.x, -p.centroid.y],
        )
        return shapely.affinity.affine_transform(
            p,
            [scale, 0, 0, scale, -p.centroid.x, -p.centroid.y],
        )

    if source == "maki":
        url = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/maki/main/icons/{name}.svg"
    elif source == "fa":
        url = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/svgs/{name}.svg"
    svgpath = pd.read_xml(requests.get(url).text).loc[0, "d"]
    return to_shapely(svgpath2mpl.parse_path(svgpath).to_polygons())


# create mapbox layers for markers.  icon defines layer and color
def marker_mapbox(
    df,
    size=0.01,
    color="blue",
    lat="lat",
    lon="lon",
):
    layers = []
    m = marker("marker", "maki")
    geoms = [
        shapely.affinity.affine_transform(m, [size, 0, 0, size, r[lon], r[lat]])
        for _, r in df.iterrows()
    ]
    layers.append(
        {
            "source": gpd.GeoSeries(geoms).__geo_interface__,
            "type": "fill",
            "color": color,
        }
    )

    return layers


df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(requests.get("https://assets.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),
    sep="Č",
    engine="python",
).rename(columns={"Latitude": "Lat", "Longitude": "Long"})
df = df.sample(50)
cd_cols = ["SubType", "Sector"]


data = []
data.append(
    {
        "type": "scattermapbox",
        "lat": df["Lat"],
        "lon": df["Long"],
        "name": "Location",
        # "hovertext": rent,
        "showlegend": False,
        "hoverinfo": "text",
        "mode": "markers",
        "customdata": df.loc[:, cd_cols].values,
        # "marker": {
        #     "symbol": "marker",
        #     # "size": 18,
        #     "opacity": 0.8,
        #     # "color": "black"
        # },
    }
)

fig = go.Figure(data).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "center": df.sample(1)
        .loc[:, ["Lat", "Long"]]
        .rename(columns={"Lat": "lat", "Long": "lon"})
        .to_dict("records")[0],
        "zoom": 4,
    },
    margin={"t": 0, "b": 0, "l": 0, "r": 0},
)

# add the markers as geojson layer...
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": marker_mapbox(df, size=0.05, lat="Lat", lon="Long", color="black")
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: We still would like hover info, so I suppose keep using circles and not markers if we're going to lose hover info functionality?

Comment: that's why I have used both in this sample code.  the standard markers have the hover info so it will display when you hover near the point.  the mapbox layers give the visual

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't cause an error and will be displayed with the default values. You need to change the icon name in the list of icons in the question. For some reason, however, not all icons can be specified. I have added icons to the [official reference as examples](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#set-marker-symbols).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_access_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=['38.91427','38.91538','38.91458',
             '38.92239','38.93222','38.90842',
             #'38.91931','38.93260','38.91368',
             #'38.88516','38.921894','38.93206',
             '38.91275'],
        lon=['-77.02827','-77.02013','-77.03155',
             '-77.04227','-77.02854','-77.02419',
             #'-77.02518','-77.03304','-77.04509',
             #'-76.99656','-77.042438','-77.02821',
             '-77.01239'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=15,
            symbol=['bus','airport','bicycle','cafe','car','music','circle'],
        ),
        text=["The coffee bar","Bistro Bohem","Black Cat",
             "Snap","Columbia Heights Coffee","Azi's Cafe",
             #"Blind Dog Cafe","Le Caprice","Filter",
             #"Peregrine","Tryst","The Coupe",
             "Big Bear Cafe"],
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=900,
    height=900,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=38.92,
            lon=-77.03
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=13
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The code I answered uses an example from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#multiple-markers).

Comment: I am specifically looking to use the `marker` icon. Does it not support the `marker` icon?

Comment: Unlike plotly's scatter plots, this one is based on mapbox, so you cannot use plotly's marker icons. I got the information from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/891).