# Plotly python Problem with adding shape to maps

Tags: python, plotly, maps, addition, shapes

I want to add a shape to my maps figure, But the result of below code is something else.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.election()


fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, 
                           locations="district", featureidkey="properties.district",
                           center={"lat": 0.0, "lon": 0.0},
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", zoom=2)

fig.add_shape(type="circle", xref="x", yref="y",
    fillcolor="PaleTurquoise", x0=0, y0=0, x1=0+.01, y1=0+.01,
    line_color="black",opacity=0.1)

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

What should I do to add a shape with a certain diameter that I want in an exact location that I want?

Comment: do you want to draw circles at defined GPS locations (lon, lat) and certain radius ?

Comment: Yes 
Exactly @RobRaymond

Answer (score 1):

Two different techniques for generating circles on a **mapbox**

1. `scatter_mapbox()` using **lat, lon, size**
2. add *geojson* layer with calculated geometry (effectively equivalent of `add_shape()` for geometric plots)

   - have randomly selected a geometry for this, could be provided separately.
   - need to consider CRS if you want to define size in meters.  epsg:4326 is expressed in degrees.  Have converted this is a UTM CRS to be able to define a radius in meters
   - then generate *geojson* for incorporation into a **mapbox** layer.  Used convenience interface of `__geo_interface__` which is available on **geopnadas** and **shapely** objects for generation
   - based on comments have demonstrated how to generate square shape as well as circle shape.  Any shape can be added,  it's just a case of using **shapely** to generate what ever you require

```
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.election()

# prep geometry
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(px.data.election_geojson())
gdf = gdf.join(
    gdf["geometry"].centroid.apply(lambda g: pd.Series({"lon": g.x, "lat": g.y}))
)

# plot circles at various lat / lon
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    df.merge(gdf, on="district"), lat="lat", lon="lon", size="total"
).update_layout(mapbox={"style": "carto-positron"})

# generate a 10000m circle at a random black as geojson
cgeo = (
    gdf.set_crs("epsg:4326")
    .sample(1)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.to_crs(d.estimate_utm_crs()))["geometry"]
    .centroid.buffer(10000)
    .to_crs("epsg:4326")
    .__geo_interface__
)
sqgeo = (
    gdf.set_crs("epsg:4326")
    .sample(1)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.to_crs(d.estimate_utm_crs()))["geometry"]
    .centroid.buffer(10000, cap_style=3)
    .to_crs("epsg:4326")
    .__geo_interface__
)

# add circle geometry as layer to mapbox figure
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": [
            {"source": cgeo, "color": "PaleTurquoise", "type": "fill", "opacity":.5},
            {"source": cgeo, "color": "black", "type": "line", "opacity": 0.1},
            {"source": sqgeo, "color": "PaleTurquoise", "type": "fill", "opacity":.5},
            {"source": sqgeo, "color": "black", "type": "line", "opacity": 0.1},

        ]
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dear @robraymond
scatter_mapbox() is great and is what I was searching for. is it possible using this command I add other shapes like rectangle, triangle and if the answer is No, What should I do for Other shapes?

Comment: have updated to demonstrate a square as well.  Any shape can be used... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689480/marker-icon-on-plotly-scattermapbox-not-updating/70723761#70723761 which allows custom marker shapes to be used

Comment: Dear @RobRaymond
Also let me know if it is possible, I need to know can use (fig = plotly.express.choropleth_mapbox) istead of (geopandas )? (Specially using fig.add_ ...)

Comment: there is no dependency between `px.choropleth_mapbox()` and **geopandas** you can use *geojson* and **locations** and **featureidkey**. However it you need to do geometry manipulations to generate layers it is far simpler if you use **geopandas** and **shapely**