# Drawing a circle on a map by given a centroid

Tags: python, plotly

I have a radius and centroid (lan=114, long=22) and I would like to plot a circle on a map to show the area impacted. On top of the circle, I want to add an arrow to show the radius. Something like this but on a map.

[image]

I found these codes from
[Plotly python Problem with adding shape to maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70692600/plotly-python-problem-with-adding-shape-to-maps)

I tried to modify it to my centroid but I am unfamiliar with plotting on a map as it isn't using the add_shape. Any help is appreciated.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.election()

# prep geometry
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(px.data.election_geojson())
gdf = gdf.join(
    gdf["geometry"].centroid.apply(lambda g: pd.Series({"lon": g.x, "lat": g.y}))
)

# plot circles at various lat / lon
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    df.merge(gdf, on="district"), lat="lat", lon="lon", size="total"
).update_layout(mapbox={"style": "carto-positron"})

# generate a 10000m circle at a random black as geojson
cgeo = (
    gdf.set_crs("epsg:4326")
    .sample(1)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.to_crs(d.estimate_utm_crs()))["geometry"]
    .centroid.buffer(10000)
    .to_crs("epsg:4326")
    .__geo_interface__
)

# add circle geometry as layer to mapbox figure
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": [
            {"source": cgeo, "color": "PaleTurquoise", "type": "fill", "opacity":.5},
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's really more of the same.

  1. The circle is as per original solution just refactored code a little
  2. The dot is just another circle with a smaller radius
  3. The arrow is constructing it as segments of a `LineString`

```
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = px.data.election()

# prep geometry
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(px.data.election_geojson())
gdf = gdf.join(
    gdf["geometry"].centroid.apply(lambda g: pd.Series({"lon": g.x, "lat": g.y}))
)

# plot circles at various lat / lon
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    df.merge(gdf, on="district"), lat="lat", lon="lon", size="total"
).update_layout(mapbox={"style": "carto-positron"})

gdf_ = gdf.set_crs("epsg:4326").sample(1)
utm = gdf_.estimate_utm_crs()
gdf_ = gdf_.to_crs(utm)
b = 10000
m = b // 10
p = gdf_.centroid.values[0]
arrow = LineString(
    [p, (p.x + b, p.y), (p.x + b - m, p.y - m), (p.x + b - m, p.y + m), (p.x + b, p.y)]
)


def geojson(shape, utm):
    return gpd.GeoSeries([shape], crs=utm).to_crs("epsg:4386").__geo_interface__


# add circle geometry as layer to mapbox figure
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": geojson(p.buffer(b), utm),
                "color": "PaleTurquoise",
                "type": "fill",
                "opacity": 0.5,
            },
            {
                "source": geojson(p.buffer(m), utm),
                "color": "red",
                "type": "fill",
                "opacity": 0.5,
            },
            {
                "source": geojson(arrow, utm),
                "color": "blue",
                "type": "line",
                "opacity": 0.5,
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for. But is that possible to add a text to indicate the radius? like '1000m' in this case

Comment: I did look into adding the text, however was just encountering mapbox bugs...  I'd suggest add it to the figure title as simple approach

Comment: what about adding to the data point? Coz I only have one centroid point to draw. I tried to create text or label but it appears when hovering only.

Answer (score 0):

I can find a solution using OpenCV, if you're open to other libraries.

[OpenCV drawing tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html)

First, you would add a circle at your centroid of specified radius. Then you would draw your line, with the initial point being the centroid, and the x2 value being centroid + radius. Roughly:

```
cv.circle(img, (x1, y1), radius, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2)
cv2.arrowedLine(img, (x1, y1), (x1+r, y1), color=(255,0,0), thickness=2, line_type=8, tipLength=0.1)
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I would like to draw it on a map